# Some links are not tappable on iOS devices

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, ios

I'm using SE full web sites on iPad and now noticed that some items are not tappable in the featured/hot block on the right side of most pages:

> [image: no tap]

This image was taken on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but same effect is on other sites too.

In Google Chrome top items can be opened only in new tabs via long tap. In Safari it is not possible at all for red circled items.

Seems the problem is more complex, in particular "Advanced Search Tips" [not tappable on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Text):

> [image: so]

Although tapping on the same link [works fine on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Text) and on [Stack Overflow for empty search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't think SE should spend time "fixing" it, since one shouldn't use the full site theme on mobile device. There is the mobile theme which provides all the basic things. Of course I'd be happy to see this fixed, just saying I would accept reply "No, we won't do that"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd using full site version is normal for tablet devices (iPad in my case). Mentioned links worked fine several days ago.

Comment: I see. Well, we can't expect them to test any change on all possible devices. :)

Comment: Did you upgrade to iOS 11?

Comment: @Catija not yet. Currently 10.3.3

Comment: OK. There was a bug report for the iOS app that was a similar problem but they had iOS 11.

Comment: @Catija what report do you mean?

Comment: You've seen it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300989/edited-button-is-hard-to-press-in-ios-11

Comment: @Catija oh, that one. In my case link is not tappable at all, not just hard but possible to tap.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I actually use the full site theme by default on my phone, simply because moderation tools don't work on mobile.