# "Edited” button is hard to press in iOS 11

Tags: bug, ios-app

The "Edited" button in blue text on Stack Exchange iOS App takes at least 6 tries to work.  Even using zoom, it takes 4 tries because it is trying to highlight the button as a normal word rather than a link.

[Video Proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzMhQYjA26o)

- App Version 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)

Comment: I have no trouble using the "Edited" button to see edit history on an iPhone 5S using iOS 10.2.1.

Comment: @PolyGeo could be an iOS 11 thing

Comment: Sorry for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqjF7HKSaaI) :)

Comment: @alexolut it’s just my computers camera.  My fingers are very close To the camera

Comment: On my iOS 11 phone, the button only works if I hold it for about 0.2 seconds instead of just tapping. Hope this is useful.